# Creating multiple pairs in R

Tags: r, match, random

I have a list of people:

```
people<-c("Betty", "Joe", "Bob", "Will", "Frank")
```

I would like to randomly assign two people to each person (self-assignment is not allowed) and I would like each person to be assigned to another an equal amount of times (in the example above each person can only be assigned to another twice).

So for example the match up could be

Betty (Joe and Bob), Joe (Bob and Will), Bob (Will and Frank), Will (Frank and Betty)

Of course I have just used their ordering but it would be nice if this could be randomised.

Any ideas where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New (easier) solution:** Using `shift` function from `TaRifx` package from Ari B. Friedman

```
tt <- sample(people)
lapply(seq_len(length(tt))-1, function(x) shift(tt, x)[1:3])
# if you don't want it to be ordered, just add a sample(.)
lapply(seq_len(length(tt))-1, function(x) sample(shift(tt, x)[1:3]))
# [[1]]
# [1] "Bob"   "Frank" "Betty"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Frank" "Betty" "Joe"  
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Betty" "Joe"   "Will" 
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Joe"  "Will" "Bob" 
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "Will"  "Bob"   "Frank"
```

---

**Old solution (for the idea):**
I'd go this way. Basically, once you `sample` "people", you can *always* go, 1,2,3, 2,3,4, 3,4,5, 4,5,1. So, let's do that. That is, generate these indices and then sample people and get the triplets.

```
# generate index
len <- length(people)
choose <- 3 # at a time 
idx <- outer(seq(choose), seq(choose+2)-1, '+')
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4    5
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6
# [3,]    3    4    5    6    7

# sample people
tt <- sample(people)
# [1] "Joe"   "Will"  "Bob"   "Frank" "Betty"
max.idx <- 2*choose + 1
tt[(len+1):max.idx] <- tt[seq(max.idx-len)]
# [1] "Joe"   "Will"  "Bob"   "Frank" "Betty" "Joe"   "Will" 

tt[idx]
#  [1] "Joe"   "Will"  "Bob"   "Will"  "Bob"   "Frank" "Bob"   "Frank" "Betty" "Frank" 
#  [15] "Betty" "Joe"  "Betty" "Joe"   "Will" 

split(tt[idx], gl(ncol(idx), nrow(idx)))
# $`1`
# [1] "Joe"  "Will" "Bob" 
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "Will"  "Bob"   "Frank"
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "Bob"   "Frank" "Betty"
# 
# $`4`
# [1] "Frank" "Betty" "Joe"  
# 
# $`5`
# [1] "Betty" "Joe"   "Will"
```

Now we can put this all in a function:

```
my_sampler <- function(x, choose) {
    len <- length(x)
    idx <- outer(seq(choose), seq(choose+2)-1, '+')
    sx  <- sample(x)
    max.idx <- 2*choose + 1
    sx[(len+1):max.idx] <- sx[seq(max.idx-len)]
    split(sx[idx], gl(ncol(idx), nrow(idx)))
}
# try it out
my_sampler(people, 3)
my_sampler(people, 4) # 4 at a time

# if you want this and want a non-ordered solution, wrap this with `lapply` and `sample`

lapply(my_sampler(people, 3), sample)
```

Comment: But only 4 triples are returned when the initial vector of names is 5 long?

Comment: The OP has only 4 in his output... So I thought that's it. will make an edit.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you mean. I thought that everyone on the list should get assigned some friends though, so no-one gets left out of the party!! :-)

Comment: +1 for a function that is going to take me a little while to understand!

Comment: it just gets the index of the form 1,2,3, 2,3,4, 3,4,5 etc.. and then pulls the corresponding sampled people.

Comment: Thanks Arun. Is there anyway to add an element of randomisation to this? People are currently ordered by last name and I do not want to make it really obvious that they are matched up with the people following them alphabetically. Is there any handy function that will reshuffle the list before applying your solution? Thanks. P.S. 'her' output Arun... :)

Comment: @Elizabeth the `sample` bit at the start reorders the list each time you use it? Or see my solution below which is also *random*.

Comment: @Elizabeth, in that case, for example, in the "new solution", you can replace `function(x) shift(tt, x)[1:3]` with `function(x) sample(shift(tt, x)[1:3])`. You just create a different combination of the 3 you picked. This way it won't be obvious.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks guys. The party is saved!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. This will get you half-way there. The bit that is missing is the constraint on people being in an equal number of partnerships. If you want to *randomly* assign two people to someone except themselves this can be achieved in a one liner like so...

```
assigns <- lapply( people , function(x) { c( x , sample( people[!(people %in% x)] , 2 ) ) } )
```

First person will be assignee and last two will be assigned.

```
assigns
#[[1]]
#[1] "Betty" "Bob"   "Will" 

#[[2]]
#[1] "Joe"   "Bob"   "Frank"

#[[3]]
#[1] "Bob"   "Betty" "Joe"  

#[[4]]
#[1] "Will"  "Betty" "Joe"  

#[[5]]
#[1] "Frank" "Will"  "Betty"
```